# What does でしょなんでだ mean?

Tags: translation, manga, reading-comprehension

[image]

What is the meaning of the sentence on the left exactly? She seems to be given the reason the forest is called like this is because of the fungi?

Comment: Those are two separate sentences. Does that clear up any confusion you have?

Comment: Just to be clear, the balloon says フシギ (不思議 = wonder), not フンギ (fungi).

Comment: What is this from? Is it from a published manga?

Comment: Yes, Ousama Ranking

Answer (score 1):

She's confused why it's called "Poison Wood" when the forest isn't poisonous.

The last two phrases

- (a) フシギでしょ
- (b) なんでだ

should be read as two separate sentences.

- (a) "How strange."
- (b) "Why?" (perhaps more rhetorically than as a real question, as @naruto suggests)

Comment: A female character who speaks like ～のよ normally doesn't say "なんでだ?", which sounds fairly masculine. But だ is actually a common particle to pose a casual quiz or riddle. So it seems to me that this "Why?" is more like "Can you guess why?" rather than "I wonder why". She already knows the answer but is giving a quiz.

Comment: @naruto I'm a bit confused.  You're saying this is a female character.  Do you knkow that from のよ?  What are you suggesting in saying she wouldn't normally say "なんでだ?"?

Comment: @naruto Or are you saying there are two speakers here?

Comment: I assume both balloons are from one female character, but one person normally doesn't say 呼ばれてるのよ (highly feminine) and なんでだ (highly masculine) in the same scene. One exception is when she's playing [だーれだ](https://hoiclue.jp/800002037.html) or some game.

Comment: They are mother and son. The character on the right is her kid.